# Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 7.0) taken image path is null

Tags: android, path, camera

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0. In my app the user takes an image and then I show it in my application. It works fine with other phones with lower Android versions (5 and 6), but for Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 7.0 the path is always null.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What method are you calling for taking a picture? Can we see some code?

Comment: Probably this should be tagged with [tag:android_camera_intent]

Comment: Check the answer(s) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34256343/192373